# typescript private readonly vs outside of class const

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, ecmascript-6, constructor

I'm wondering whats the best approach or if there is any consequence when referring to outside of the class constants in the same file.

The problem arouse when I was declaring a simple class that would throw an error when receiving an invalid parameter:

```js
export class Digit {
  private _value: number = null;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }

    this._value = value;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

}
```

That *value* setter would never trigger in the constructor as the class needs to be instantiated to do so.

Because I want to keep things simple, I just want this example class to hold a valid digit or to not exist at all, so I don't want to instantiate it with null on its *value*. This led me to the following code:

```js
export class Digit {
  private _value: number = null;

  constructor(value: number) {
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }

    this._value = value;
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }

    this._value = value;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

}
```

Which works fine but now I'm repeating myself! Imagine doing a validation like that for 10 or more fields.

So I thought about two solutions:

1- Refactor into a validation function inside of class

```js
export class Digit {
  private _value: number = null;

  private readonly validateValue = function (value: number): number {
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }

    return value;
  };

  constructor(value: number) {
    this._value = this.validateValue(value);
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    this._value = this.validateValue(value);
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

}
```

I like this approach because all the business logic is contained inside of the class. But its still reachable outside of this if you choose not to respect the private scope.
The thing i don't like about it is that the class gets cluttered easily as more and more fields and validations are added, then it gets distracting to the eye, as you may be wanting to fix some behavior knowing that your instance values are correct.

2- Refactor into a validation function outside of class but in the same file

```
const validateValue = function (value: number): number {
  if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }

  return value;
};

export class Digit {
  private _value: number = null;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this._value = validateValue(value);
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    this._value = validateValue(value);
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

}
```

What I like about this approach is that I can go straight to my class code with the precondition that values are correct and validated and I'm not being distracted by them inside of my class. Plus I can't choose to omit a private scope and access its validators.

Also if validations get really extensive I can choose to create a helper for the class and refactor the validations outside of the file (don't know if that's a bad practice).

On the other hand I don't know about the consequences of using these outside of class declarations.

So what would be the best approach for this problem? Are both solutions valid?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: If the constant is a primitive type (e.g. number, string) or enum make it an out-of-class constant. Export it. Whatever. It's a const declared primitive: it's not going to change on you. If it's a reference type (object, array), and only if it's a reference type, should you even *consider* making it a private property.

Comment: This question has no correct answer and will bring in a lot of opinions rather than fact based approaches. Generally, asking for the "best" or "better" approach does that, when you don't give objective criteria for what those modifiers mean.

Comment: ^^ as such there are 3 votes (including mine) to close as primarily opinion based

Comment: The whole point of using a type-system is not to rely on runtime type-checking! Anything code that calls `myDigit.value = x` where `x` is not a `number` should throw a compile-time error.

Comment: @user633183 and that's what it does! NaN *is a number* unfortunately ...

Comment: `NaN`, "not a number", has type `number`... and that's typescript, ladies and gentleman -_-

Comment: @jhpratt "all good questions generate some degree of opinion" ...

Comment: @user633183 You're right about that but I'm expecting to receive input at runtime and try catch errors.

Comment: @JonasWilms There's a big difference between that and _literally_ asking what the best approach is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally introduce another type, e.g. `NotNaN`:

```
type NotNaN = number & { __notNaN: true };
```

Then you can write a validator for that:

```
function notNaN(n: any): n is NotNaN {
  return !isNaN(n);
}
```

And also type your class properties accordingly:

```
class Digit {
  constructor(public value: NotNaN) { }
}
```

Then you can write things like:

```
let digit = new Digit(12 as NotNaN);
let someValue = +prompt("Surprise me!");

// Properly checked, works:
if(notNaN(someValue)) {
  digit.value = someValue;
}

// Not properly checked:
digit.value = someValue;
// TypeError: type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NotNaN'
```

That way, you can avoid getters / setters at all. Throwing errors is not a good idea, instead you should properly validate inputs & operations, and thats what this enforces.

Comment: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sGBDGUC8UB2BXAtgIwgCcoAyKAbygH1rMFkYAuKYI7aAXygB8oBGXlABMQ-sIDcAKCkAzbJgDGwAJZxMWBigAUmFkkwgAlCw0qAzrC2oKUqFCIRg2IhoCEFxrqPTOMqYoANkjmlgAiKgDmKsCUdlCK6uZs2MpwRNpg2PiBKopQAG5IgRws8IgoRpRQfn4ygU5QACZRMehYEADuUBHRwNriPlINseZwuBAAasUc7QDUmUTjYP0ARADKLmBEFtATbqtVPHyrh9ItfQB0RSXQGGMT07fSKrK61toPUzMQRlW29guMWuP3aXyeHF8QA)

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't that enforce the check outside of the class? Who better than the class itself knows which values it can hold? Imagine the same class with 10 attributes and different type validations for each one.
 Also why throwing Errors is not a good idea?

Comment: @Julián right, it enforces *the developer* to directly validate input data & math operations. I admit that this might add some overhead due to some unneccessary guards (seems as if numer literal types will get more powerful soon, then this might get more elegant)

Comment: @Juliánn errors are thrown at runtime. Instead of handling the errors somehow, this enforces you to proactively check the data, and that way you can also directly give user feedback etc.

Comment: "Who better than the class itself knows which values it can hold?", right, thats why the type specifies that.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. You mean adding the validation on the inputs on the frontend, detecting the error before the instance is ever created. If that's the case I find the use of types useful, the thing is that i have to add logic to the frontend every time instead of just reusing the same class. Plus, having the business logic inside of the class gives me the advantage of also reusing it in the backend. try catching errors then would allow me to just report the error to a user via a dialog or via an http response. What do you think about it in that case?

Comment: Well then it really depends. I'm generally not a friend of validation inside of getters/setters, but if thats whats works best for you ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a "right" answer here. I would personally prefer there to be a single implementation for setting the value, then you can call that implementation from the constructor.

```
export class Digit {
  private _value: number = null;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.setValue(value);
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    this.setValue(value);
  }

  get valor() {
    return this._value;
  }

  private setValue(value: number) {
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error('Received NaN as digit.'); }
    this._value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yeah that looks fine to me, but it kind of makes me feel like the setter is wasted, as you have a `set value` and then a `setValue` inside of the class.

Comment: As you said "That value setter would never trigger in the constructor as the class needs to be instantiated to do so," given your setter requirement I don't know of a different way to avoid repeating yourself.